# Given an HTTP Cookie, how do I ensure that the value stored in it is the latest

Tags: node.js, web-services, cookies

I am currently running into an issue of concurrent requests, NodeJS, with access points to a cookie that holds information that I attain from a server. The thing is the requests being made are asynchronous, and need to remain that way, but I am in charge of asking for the new data sets when the cookie is about to become stale. How do i keep updating the cookie without bogging the server down with requests for a new cookie, if multiple concurrent requests all assume that they are the ones that should be in charge of refreshing the cookie's value.

I.e. Req1->Req30 are fired off. In the process of handling Req17 the cookies time to live is caught so it sends out the refresh command. The thing is Req18->Req30 all assume that they should be the ones to refresh the cookies value, because they also do the staleness checks and fail in that respect.

I have limited ability to actively change the server side code, and due to the sensitive nature of the data cannot readily decide to place it in a DB because at that point, I become charged with ensuring that the data is again secured.

Should I just store multiple key/values in the cookie, and iterate through them, this could become an expensive operation. Also could overwrite the cookie with invalid data on some request, since to update the cookie and append the new key value pairs requires creating a new one, due to immutability with the cookies themselves.

Comment: You are saying your node.js have concurrency, do you have multiple workers?

Comment: The NodeJS is a proxy to the actual server base. All the code within it is async wherever it could be to boost performance a bit. The second point would be that I can't store the data in the application, due to the use of multiple instances when load balancing the server.

Comment: Maybe you should not fire the check of the cookie on every worker you have in first place. Because even if you handle the concurrence of the cookie renewal you still have X checks. Why not just have one worker looking at it?

Comment: The thing is the cookie needs to never contain stale data, or at least no reference stale data. If I only have one thing checking for it's validity, once that process sends the cookie forward, wouldn't it then get invalidated by the next request that sends the cookie forward? Should I just make a check loop function that constantly sends a check for the cookie, but only actually set it from that function, so the other requests don't accidentally overwrite that cookie, they can only read it.

Comment: If you have one request that update the cookie, and all others to read it, it's gonna work. Ofc there still can be asynchronous access trouble if you have some concurrent execution. You can fix it by using timestamps in cookie. When you store a data, attach a timestamp to it. When you set the cookie, if the new timestamp is more recent than the previous one you perform the change, else you don't.

With this full solution we did two things: 1 you i'll have a lot less function that perform cookie checking, and so a lot less requests. 2 you won't have outdated data.

Comment: Main thing that I see with this approach, that I didnt think to take care of, is that even if Req18-Req30 use the older value, the validity of the new instance does not invalidate the old one, at least not instantly due to it's time to live not having been met. This would nullify access issues, and of course cut down on the amount of requests that I in turn make. If you'd like to push this off as the answer for this specific method, I'd end up saying it's accepted as the answer I'd been looking for. I tried an approach close to this, but got lost in the timing aspect of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle concurrent access on the cookie :

- Use of timestamp; only perform the change if the data is more recent

---

To handle cookie data renewal :

- Instead of having workers to perform the check of new data concurrently. Ask one specific worker to handle data update, meanwhile others workers use the data in read only mode.